# Añadir etiqueta HTML usando Blade sin Laravel

Tags: php, blade

Me gustaría mostrar una etiqueta `<i></i>` en el html, pero esta etiqueta es una variable de tipo texto, y me muestra literalmente `<i class='fas fa-question-circle'></i>` en el html en lugar de un icono. He probado usando `{!! !!}` y `{{ html_entity_decode($variable) }}` pero ninguna ha dado el resultado deseado.

Creo que el que no funcionen estas dos ultimas opciones se debe a que estoy usando blade sin usar laravel [(duncan3dc/blade)](https://packagist.org/packages/duncan3dc/blade).

Comment: Pregunta: ¿Porque quieres agregar toda la etiqueta completa? Si simplemente puedes guardar la `clase` y en html poner `<i class="{{$var}}"></i>`

Comment: @JuanRivera Al fiinal es como lo he solucionado, igualmente gracias por tu solucion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion seria imprimirlo con [print-PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.print.php) para que te salga segun el fomato que pusistes

```
@php print '<i class='fas fa-question-circle'></i>'; @endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

Como comenta [@JuanRivera](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/178674/juan-rivera) he optado por guardar en la variable únicamente `fas fa-question-circle` y despues mostrarlo de esta forma: `<i class="{{$var}}"></i>`